# ServiceStack set up packages

Tags: servicestack

I'm trying on ServiceStack but getting stuck in the installation. Can I ask what's the correct packages to install? For a very simple tutorial on Pluralsight.

It doesn't seem to allow me to enable `using ServiceStack.Interfaces` or `using ServiceStack.ServiceInterface` in my application. Even though those are right there in the References.

I have installed `ServiceStrack, ServiceStack.Host.MVC, ServiceStack.Host.AspNet` and more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to install ServiceStack is with [ServiceStackVS VS.NET Extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5bd40817-0986-444d-a77d-482e43a48da7) which will download the right packages for each project type. See this guide on [Creating your first project with ServiceStackVS](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Creating-your-first-project).

If you want to add packages manually to a normal ASP.NET Web Application please see [Creating a Service from Scratch](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Create-your-first-webservice).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to build just minimal web-service, you do not need to install Host.MVC or Host.AspNet, just install the minimal package using NuGet Package Manager like this:

> Install-Package ServiceStack

After that you can use this [guide](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Create-your-first-webservice) to configure your newly ServiceStack Web-Service.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. But I did install ServiceStack. ServiceStackVS from Nuget, and because of the problem, I wouldn't mind to manually type in to install all the packages I could find (including Host.AspNet, Host.MVC, Logging etc). Yet I still couldn't use ServiceStack.Interfaces and for god's sake, it is in the References. It is extremely frustrating and I was wondering why couldn't they make it more straightforward.

Comment: @KEIOKRYSHA what version that you intend to install? is it ServiceStack V3 or V4?

Comment: Hi, I am using the latest one. So I assume it is V4? Honestly, it has nowhere indicating its version. So I don't know. I installed ServiceStackVS and there are templates in Visual Studio ready for use. Anyway, I eventually found out they dramatically changed the namespaces. I would suggest the development team put this information on top of their website to avoid frustration. The tutorial I was referring to is a few years old so the namespaces were messed up.

Comment: well, ServiceStack have major changes because they have commercial version (V4) on late 2013 to 2014. if you use tutorial that created before that, you need to use V3. and this is the documentation link for V3 https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/v3